# 〜を望む vs. 〜楽しみにしている

Tags: nuances

My textbook says 〜を望む means "look forward to". I usually use 〜楽しみにしている for this purpose. What's the difference?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's 「～を望む」, not 「～を待ち望む」?

Comment: @Chocolate, I have never heard that expression. When is it used?

Comment: ^「[待]{ま}ち[望]{のぞ}む」は、「楽しみに待つ・期待して待つ」("look forward to" "anticipate" "await eagerly ") って意味で、少しフォーマルな言い方です。

Comment: Added a picture.

Comment: ^ 確かに「望む look forward to」って書いてありますね・・。　「結婚を望む」ってどっちかっていうと "hope/want to marry/get married" 「結婚したい」みたいな感じですよね・・

Comment: "Look forward to getting married" implies it's going to happen, so the person is engaged or something. "Hope to get married" implies no degree of certainty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure your textbook says "nozomu" means "look forward to"? Because

望む nozomu basically means "to hope for/to desire", NOT "to look forward to". As you thought, 楽しむ tanoshimu means "to enjoy/have fun".　楽しみにする means "to look forward to"

I am not sure why your textbook would make such a claim. I am tempted to say it's either a typo or some sort of misunderstanding.

thanks @Yuuichi Tam for pointing out an earlier error.

Thanks for including the photo of your textbook entry. It clears things up a lot. @Chocolate is right in his/her comment, the textbook's use of 望む there reads MUCH more like "hope to get married" or "really want to get married" . I have never seen this phrase before. It seems like an odd pairing.

Although, now that I think about it, a bride or groom might think it's strange to use 楽しみにしている for 結婚. It's an interesting question.

Searching for instances of 結婚を望む online, there are over 400,000 hits, but the phrase is used on those webpages (the few I checked) to talk about a strong desire to get married.

Comment: I want to correct your answer a bit. 楽しむ doesn't mean "to look forward to" but "enjoy".